# Pass data between two web pages on the same machine with no postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am creating a web page that offers the user the ability to "undock" a control into a new browser window. When the user selects a value in the new window, I need to have the new page pass data to the parent page and  update some information on the screen. Basically, I need to keep the data displayed in sync. I am using jQuery and AJAX to avoid any postbacks and I would want to do the same for this. For example: The user does a search for "foo" on parent page and wants to see the results in a larger format. He clicks the "undock" button and larger window opens with the search results. The user selects a value from the child window and the parent window is updated as well. I would think I could accomplish this with AJAX but have yet to find a good post explaining it. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Also, if the child windows gets closed and I don't capture the close because of a browser crash, is there a way the parent can check to see if the child is still there?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I pass a JavaScript variable to another browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window)

Comment: It does talk about using the window.opener but I was wondering if there is a way via AJAX.

Comment: Ajax is simply a way for a browser to communicate with a server and receive a response *without doing a full post back*...  At it's heart, it is javascript.  So I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "via AJAX"

Comment: I was thinking there was some way to use AJAX to post data from one page to the other. I played with the opener and found I can invoke a click() event on a control in the parent page from the child. I think that will get me where I need to be for my current task. I also found that the object returned from the window.open has a property “closed” I can use to see if the child was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do your undock, are you using window.open?  You can use window.opener to communicate between two windows: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Answer (score 0):

you could try using [socket.io](http://socket.io), but it might be overkill for your scenario...

Answer (score 0):

check out, if this works for you:

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/03/10/using-html5-web-storage-for-interprocess-communication.aspx

cheers
sascha

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use window.parent from the child window?