# Passing JS array to another page without PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some data stored in a JavaScript array which I want to send to some other page. Is it possible to do this without utilizing any server-side scripting like PHP? Can it be done with JS or jQuery or something like that? Ideally, I want to be able to access that array in my JS script on the other page.

Thank you

Comment: You can use localStorage or cookies to save this data, then fetch it back at 'some other page'.

Comment: You can try setting a cookie with the data on the first page, and getting the cookie with the data on the second page.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate from [this][1] SO question, chek it out mate.
You can send an object to another page if you're opening it from window.open method.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize your Array/Objects into a String using

`JSON.stringify`

so if you have an Array like

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
JSON.stringify(arr) // "[1,2,3,4]"
```

And then pass it using an GET parameter to your other page

In which you could acces it using something like this

```
function get(q,s) { 
        s |= window.location.search; 
        var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i'); 
        return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' :     decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined; 
    }
```

If you'r url were `www.example.com/?arr="[1,2,3]"`

`get("arr")`

Would return

`"[1,2,3]"`

of course you could also store this String in a `Cookie` or in the `localStorage`
Object (*which is only supported by modern browsers*)

Then you can use

`JSON.parse`

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[1,2,3,4]");
arr // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: IE8 supports `localStorage` as well.

Comment: Thx, i'll add a compatibility table,  when i'm back from mobile

Comment: Thank you for the reply Glutamat. I would prefer to use JSON then cookies or localStorage since it seems like a more robust option. However, you mention sending it using POST. It is my understanding that POST can only be read by the server, which is not possible in my case (or else I would just have used PHP). I'm not even sure that GET can work either. How would you go about actually passing the data to the other page once it has been converted into the JSON string?

Comment: Ok, so I ended up using your suggestion and passing it through `localStorage`. Keeping my fingers crossed for no old browsers :)

Comment: @NobleK Updated the answer with get parameters, sorry i don't had the time to do this nicely, as its christmas and i have no time right now, hope this helps you