# Is there any way to pass Dart variables to another browser window?

Tags: dart

I know that I can use local storage, cookies and postMessage but all these methods only accept simple types. I want to pass objects and lists directly to the other window.

I found a similar question but using javascript. I'd like to do something just like Victor pointed in the following link.

[Can I pass a JavaScript variable to another browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window)

Trying anything similar in Dart gives me a warining even before running.

`var popup = window.open('popup.html', '');
popup.variable = localVariable; //warning here`

Comment: Have you tried serialising the variable to a string (maybe just JSON) first, and then deserializing it in the new window?

Comment: Yes, and that's my first alternative right now. But if possible to pass directly like in that JS code, I'd use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing objects is not possible.

You can serialize to JSON to make it a simple type and pass it using postMessage and then deserialize.
Lists and maps containing only simple types should work with postMessage.