# Javascript - new tab + enter data

Tags: javascript

I only have a basic understanding of javascript, and was considering whether it would be possible for me to make a small utility that opens an url in a new tab, and then proceeds to enter a value from the utility site into a text field on the website in the new tab.

I could see why browsers would want to prevent this behavior for security reasons, but what I want to do, is basically just to automate this proces so I don't have to do it.

Is this possible? If so, how? (code examples not required)

I've been using Selenium before, and this would be my alternative solution if it can't be done with JS.

Thank you

Comment: Although this post is way older, I think it might help you: [Can I pass a JavaScript variable to another browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no posibility to open *new tab* but you can open the new window. Just add the data you need into the URL and catch it in the opened window running appropriate function to do the stuff you need.

```
window.open('/target?data=' + data);
```

Also you can pass the data directly in the window instance:

```
var w = window.open('/target');
w.data = data;
```