# change on the javascript function is not being reflected in the browser

Tags: javascript, drupal-webform

I've difficult closing popup. `window.close();` is working only with **Chrome** not **IE**. After doing some researches, I found [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) which tells why I shouldn't use `window.close()` directly in the popup to close it.

```
//Global var to store a reference to the opened window
var openedWindow;

function openWindow() {
  openedWindow = window.open('moreinfo.htm');
}

function closeOpenedWindow() {
    openedWindow.close();
}

function myReload() {
   location.reload();
}
```

The problem is that the first time I wrote the closeOpenWindow method, I forgot to put the `()` at the end, so it was `openedWindow.close;`

I've fixed the problem, but I'm still getting the same error on that line.

```
openedWindow.close is not a function
```

If I delete the the entire function `closeOpenedWindow()`, I get the error that closeOpenedWindow() is not a function. When I put it back, I get the previous error that `openedWindow.close is not a function.`

Thanks for helping

## EDIT:

This is how I'm calling the function from the popupu:

```
function mycloseChild() {
  window.opener.myReload();
  window.opener.closeOpenedWindow();
}
```

Comment: Use the dev tools to find out what `openedWindow` is.

Comment: What does `console.log(openedWindow.close);` show?

Comment: @Barmar, I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError:: openedWindow is not defined at <anonymous> 1:13`. Please see edit.

Comment: What are `myReload()` and `myCloseChild()`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this seems to work in Chrome Debugger.  Maybe a timing issue?

```
//Global var to store a reference to the opened window
var openedWindow;

function openWindow() {
  openedWindow = window.open('moreinfo.htm');
}

function closeOpenedWindow() {
    openedWindow.close();
}

openWindow();
//openedWindow is new window
closeOpenedWindow();
//openedWindow closes
```

It looks like you can use `window.opener` from the openedWindow to get a reference to the original window object which has the method `closeOpenedWindow`.  but in order for that to work, you need to add `closeOpenedWindow` to the original window like so

```
window['closeOpenedWindow'] = function() {
    openedWindow.close();
}
```

and then call it from the opened window like so `window.opener.closeOpenedWindow()`

see also [Can I pass a JavaScript variable to another browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window)

Comment: `OpenWindow` and `CloseOpenedWindow` are defined in the parent page. `CloseOpenWindow` is being called from the `popup`.

Comment: well, that's your problem then, no?  The popup is a new window with no reference to openedWindow.  see updated answer

Comment: I think so, because when I run `console.log(openedWindow);` from the popup, this is the response I'me getting: `Uncaught ReferenceError:: openedWindow is not defined at <anonymous> `

Comment: if you attach the function to the opener as described above, you should be able to `window.opener.closeOpenedWindow()` granted in same security domain.

Comment: I've made the modification you mentioned above. I even change the name of the window from `openedWindow` to `popup`, It still complains that `popup is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var openedWindow = {
    open: () => { window.open('moreinfo.htm') },
    close: () => { window.close() }
}
```

Comment: Yup, it's ES6. You could just use: `open: function() { window.open('...') }

Comment: I just realized that this is for drupal webForms... Not sure if you can use ES6 with that. You might be need babel to transpile it correctly.

Comment: My mistake. This is not a `Drupal form`. It's `asp.net webform 4.0`. I've just fixed the tag.