# Can you "connect" two pages so that actions on one page affect the other?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs, connection

Bit of a weird question: let's say I have two pages, so two index.html files, each with their content and js scripts, nothing fancy. I would like to be able to open them both on different tabs and then, for example, click a button on page1 and have something happen as a result in page2. Can this be done?

Comment: You need SignalR (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr). It allows send/receive message from client to server to client.

Comment: look up websockets

Comment: This question has been answered here. Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window

Comment: I think I managed to do what I need using window.postMessage(), I'll try using that

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this (off the top of my head):

1. You need a database and a server. Then one page can change values in the database and the other can check those values.
2. You use one page to download and use files from another (eg. an image). This isn't very interactive though as it can't take any information that didn't exist on page load.